# How do I get the equations of motion starting from this Hamiltonian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, integration

So I have a very complicated Hamiltonian given by:

$$ H_R(\psi, P_\psi) = \frac{-B_0 R^3}{2 \pi} (2 \psi - sin(2 \psi) + \sqrt{B_0^6 R^6 V(\psi)^2 - P_\psi^2} $$

where

$$V(\psi) = \frac{1}{\pi} \sqrt{b_0^4 sin^4(\psi) + (\pi P/M - \psi + \frac{1}{2}sin(2\psi))^2}.$$

The potential makes this Hamiltonian VERY hard (according to me) to evaluate. My goal is to get the equation of motion on form $\psi(R)=$ something, for arbitrary $P/M$. $B_0$ and $b_0$ are just some constants.

In principle I could start from

$$ \frac{\partial H_R(\psi, P_\psi)}{\partial P_\psi} = \partial_R \psi \equiv \dot{\psi}.$$

Then I would get

$$ \dot{\psi} = \frac{-P_\psi}{\sqrt{B_0^2 R^6 V(\psi)^2 - P_\psi}}. $$

Then I could integrate $\psi(R)$ w.r.t $R$. But I don't know the limits of this integral. And even if I did, it would be a next to impossible task to integrate? Not even Mathematica can handle that integral.

So I will have to make some approximations I guess.

I could in principle solve it numerically but I want a solution for arbitrary $P/M$.

Any input on how I can ultimately get the equation of motion on form $\psi(R) = $ something?

I am grateful for any help.

$P_{\psi}$ is canonical momenta in $\psi$ which is the polar angle spanning a 3-sphere. P and M is the momentum and mass of a D-brane or graviton. The range of $\psi$ is $[0, 2 \pi]$

Comment: What are $P_{\psi}, P, M$ ?  Are they related ?  Presumably $\psi$ is an angle, but covering what range of values ?

Comment: Thanks! Will edit to make this clearer. $P_psi$ is canonical momenta in $\psi$ which is the polar angle spanning a 3-sphere. P and M is the momentum and mass of the field on the question. The range of $\psi$ is $[0, 2 \pi]$

Comment: You said "Then I could integrate $\psi(R)$...w.r.t R". Where is the equation for $d\psi/dR$? R seems to be just a parameter. Perhaps you mean to integrate the $d_t\psi=...$ equation to get $\psi(R,t)$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I believe that equation is simply Hamilton's equation of motion: $ (d/dR) \psi = \partial H / \partial P_{\psi} $. R is a radial coordinate in $\mathbf{R}^4$

Comment: Use Hamilton-Jacobi equation, substitute: $H \to \frac{\partial S}{\partial t}$ and $P_\psi \to \frac{\partial S}{\partial \psi}$ and look for a solution $S=-Et+W(\psi)$. This way you'll get $W$ as an integral. Differentiate so obtained result with respect to $E$ (the only integral of motion) and equate the derivative to a constant. This way you'll have an equation relating time and coordinate, schematically: $t-t_0=f(\psi)$

Answer (score 0):

from the  Hamiltonian :

$$H=H(\psi,P_\psi)$$

you get two first order differential equations :

$$\dot{P}_\psi=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial \psi}=f_1(P_\psi\,,\psi)\tag 1$$
$$\dot{\psi}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial P_\psi}=f_2(P_\psi\,,\psi)\tag 2$$

if you linearized Eq. (1) and (2), you obtain analytical solution.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
  \Delta{\dot P}_\psi \\
  \Delta{\dot{\psi}} \\
\end{bmatrix}=\left[ \begin {array}{cc} {\frac {\partial }{\partial P_{{\psi}}}}f_{
{1}} \left( P_{{\psi}},\psi \right) &{\frac {\partial }{\partial \psi}
}f_{{1}} \left( P_{{\psi}},\psi \right) \\ {\frac {
\partial }{\partial P_{{\psi}}}}f_{{2}} \left( P_{{\psi}},\psi
 \right) &{\frac {\partial }{\partial \psi}}f_{{2}} \left( P_{{\psi}},
\psi \right) \end {array} \right]_{[P_\psi=P_{\psi_0},\psi=\psi_0]}
\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \Delta{ P}_\psi \\
  \Delta{{\psi}} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$